# Android Recycleview dragging items within a nested recyclerview for the second time is not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, itemtouchhelper

**I attempted to integrate the dragging feature for both the primary item and the extended list within that list.**

**It functioned OK, however when I closed and reopened an item, the item (in extended list) stopped moving with the cursor.**

Check out this video to understand the issue.
[video link](https://www.veed.io/view/feb190bd-5455-4c5d-bf8f-23a334e77e6e?panel=share)

Adapter code.

```
class ItemAdapter(private val items: MutableList<ItemModel>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private var expandedItemPosition: Int = -1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ItemListBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_list, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(items[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
            items[i] = items.set(i + 1, items[i])
        }
    } else {
        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
            items[i] = items.set(i - 1, items[i])
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
}

inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemListBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            val position = adapterPosition
            expandedItemPosition = if (position == expandedItemPosition) {
                -1 // Collapse the currently expanded item
            } else {
                position // Expand the clicked item
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged() // Notify the adapter of the item changes
        }
    }

    fun bind(item: ItemModel) {
        binding.viewModel = item
        val isExpanded = adapterPosition == expandedItemPosition
        binding.isExpanded = isExpanded
        binding.executePendingBindings()

        if (isExpanded) {
            val expandedRecyclerView = binding.expandedRecyclerView
            expandedRecyclerView.adapter = ExpandedItemAdapter(item.expandedList)

            val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
                0
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                ): Boolean {
                    val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                    val toPosition = target.adapterPosition
                    (expandedRecyclerView.adapter as ExpandedItemAdapter).onItemMove(
                        fromPosition,
                        toPosition
                    )
                    return true
                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    Log.d("CheckingSwiped", "onSwiped: $adapterPosition")
                }

                override fun onMoved(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    fromPos: Int,
                    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    toPos: Int,
                    x: Int,
                    y: Int
                ) {
                    Log.d("CheckingSwiped", "onMoved: $fromPos ::: $toPos")

                    super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y)
                }

                override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
            })

            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(expandedRecyclerView)
        } else {
            binding.expandedRecyclerView.adapter = null
        }
    }
}

}
```

If you identify any errors in my code, please let me know and give a solution. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code may be it helpful

```
class ItemAdapter(private val items: MutableList<ItemModel>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private var expandedItemPosition: Int = -1
private var itemTouchHelper: ItemTouchHelper? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ItemListBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_list, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(items[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
            items[i] = items.set(i + 1, items[i])
        }
    } else {
        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
            items[i] = items.set(i - 1, items[i])
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
}

inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemListBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            val position = adapterPosition
            expandedItemPosition = if (position == expandedItemPosition) {
                -1 // Collapse the currently expanded item
            } else {
                position // Expand the clicked item
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged() // Notify the adapter of the item changes
        }
    }

    fun bind(item: ItemModel) {
        binding.viewModel = item
        val isExpanded = adapterPosition == expandedItemPosition
        binding.isExpanded = isExpanded
        binding.executePendingBindings()

        val expandedRecyclerView = binding.expandedRecyclerView
        if (isExpanded) {
            expandedRecyclerView.adapter = ExpandedItemAdapter(item.expandedList)
        } else {
            expandedRecyclerView.adapter = null
        }

        if (itemTouchHelper == null) {
            itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
                0
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                ): Boolean {
                    val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                    val toPosition = target.adapterPosition
                    (expandedRecyclerView.adapter as? ExpandedItemAdapter)?.onItemMove(
                        fromPosition,
                        toPosition
                    )
                    return true
                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    Log.d("CheckingSwiped", "onSwiped: $adapterPosition")
                }

                override fun onMoved(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                fromPos: Int,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                toPos: Int,
                x: Int,
                y: Int
            ) {
                Log.d("CheckingSwiped", "onMoved: $fromPos ::: $toPos")

                super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y)
            }

            override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })

        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(expandedRecyclerView)
    } else {
        binding.expandedRecyclerView.adapter = null
    }
}
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
From this I got an idea to resolve this issue .


Firstly I changed the scope of itemTouchHelper to global,
 
than before initializing I check if itemTouchHelper is not null than removed the attachment like this. 
[>>itemTouchHelper?.attachToRecyclerView(null) ]
and than initialize it. 
[>> itemTouchHelper =ItemTouchHelper(...) ]

Comment: Full code :- https://github.com/Mohammad-Taqi/Recycleview-with-Expandable-and-drag-drop-Items.git